# Sort ActiveRecords By Multiple Fields

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am trying to sort my query results using 2 fields, `created_at` and `job_code`. The issue I'm having is that the `job_code` is composed of a string that contains numbers and letters which apparently the sort_by method isn't liking.

```
def structure_jobs(jobs)
  jobs.sort_by{|j| [j.created_at, j.job_code]}.reverse
end

Sample Data:
created_at     |    job_code
Jul-22-2014         140987E
Jul-22-2014         1482923
Jul-22-2014         140987Z
Mar-15-2014         12N7Y65

Results Wanted:
created_at     |    job_code
Jul-22-2014         1482923
Jul-22-2014         140987Z
Jul-22-2014         140987E
Mar-15-2014         12N7Y65
```

I sort by DESC `created_at` order, so newest to oldest. If they match on the date then sort by `job_code` could be in DESC/ASC order doesn't matter as long as they still sort accordingly to their respective order.

Comment: If you want them both descending then `jobs.sort_by{|j| [j.created_at, j.job_code]}.reverse` should be fine, `sort_by` will only give you problems if you want to mix ascending and descending with non-numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be doing the sorting inside the database:

```
query.order('created_at desc, job_code asc')
```

But if you must sort in Ruby then why not use [`sort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) instead of [`sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)? `sort_by` is great for simple things but requires strange contortions when you need to reverse-sort one of the components and you can't (cleanly) use simple tricks like negating a number to reverse the order. Using `sort` you could say:

```
jobs.sort do |a, b|
  if((b.created_at <=> a.created_at) == 0)
    a.job_code <=> b.job_code
  else
    b.created_at <=> a.created_at
  end
end
```

to sort descending on `created_at` and ascending on `job_code`. For ascending `created_at` and descending `job_code` you reverse the `a`s and `b`s:

```
jobs.sort do |a, b|
  if((a.created_at <=> b.created_at) == 0)
    b.job_code <=> a.job_code
  else
    a.created_at <=> b.created_at
  end
end
```

If you're sorting both `created_at` and `job_code` ascending then

```
jobs.sort_by{|j| [j.created_at, j.job_code]}
```

should work fine. If you're sorting both descending then:

```
jobs.sort_by{|j| [j.created_at, j.job_code]}.reverse
```

should work fine.

Demo (based on falsetru's): http://ideone.com/L2vMST

Comment: Thanks for your help with this issue. In essence your suggestions work perfectly with the data I've given. However, I am still not getting things to sort out properly. I realized that some `job_code` fields are empty which may be causing issues. Regardless of this your solution perfectly answers my question given the data I have provided.

Comment: What does "empty" mean? Are they `nil` (AKA NULL inside the database) or empty strings?

Comment: By empty I am referring to empty string. The issue is I am running into the case where in "DESC" order for both I am getting 140598E, 1482923, 140598Z all three of which have the same `created_at`

Comment: What order should those three come out in? What order do they come out in? Where would you want an empty string to appear?

Comment: Ideally I would want them to be in desc order so 1482923, 140598Z, 140598E with empty strings going at the end. To summarize I want records in desc order by `created_at` and in the event of them being equal sort those by `job_code`. If `created_at` are the same I want to order those that match in desc order with empty strings at the bottom.

Comment: Then adjust the `sort` block appropriately. You don't have to use `<=>` for comparisons, you can compare any way you want as long as you return -1, 0, or 1 and your comparison is well defined.

Comment: I went ahead with using the `sort` and after some time of fine tuning I was able to sort how I needed to. Thank you for all your help!!